# How do we know that if $Ax = b$ has a unique solution, $A$ is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

We are of course assuming $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix.

I know there's a proof of it going the other way (invertibility implies a unique solution), but I'm trying to work out a proof going this way.

I'm looking for a proof that only uses the most basic concepts of linear algebra.

I know that:

1) Every matrix can be reduced to rref.

2) Elementary row operations do not change the solution set of $Ax = b$.

3) I also know that $Ix = y$, where $y$ is the particular solution.

I'm not sure how to prove that $[A|b]$ can be reduced to $[I|y]$, however, and that's where the problem lies.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if $Ax=b$ and $Ay=b$ then $A(x-y)=0$ but since $A$ is invertible, it implies $x-y=0$ ie $x=y$. Moreover, the system admits the solution $x=A^{-1}b$

Comment: The OP is looking for the other direction: unique solution implies invertibility.

Answer (score 13):

Suppose $A$ were not invertible. Then, there would be a non-zero vector in its null space. Call this vector $z$. Compute $y$ such that $z = x-y$. Since $z$ is non-zero, $x\neq y$.

Then, $$Az = 0 \implies A(x-y) = 0 \implies Ax-Ay = 0  \implies Ax = Ay.$$

But since $Ax = b$ then $Ay = b$. But $x$ was the unique solution to $Ax=b$, so $x=y$ necessarily, contradicting $x \neq y$.

Comment: Hi, I'm currently also thinking this problem out. I have some concerns however, how do you draw the conclusion that if A is not invertible, then there would be a non zero vector in its null space. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

if there's no solutions then you know $A$ is not invertible. on the other hand if there is at least one solution and if $A$ is not invertible then the set of vectors $x$ such that $Ax = 0$ is not trivial (contains some nonzero vector). do you see how to show that your solution to $Ax = b$ is not unique in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If $A\in M_n(F)$ then let $f:F^n\to F^n$ be the canonically associated endomorphism to the matrix $A$. The equation $Ax=b$ can be written $f(x)=b$ and saying that this equation has a unique solution is only saying that $b$ has a unique preimage by $f$. So in order to say that $f$ is bijective we need to have that **for each** $b$ the equation $f(x)=b$ has a unique solution $x$. In matrix language,  you need that the equation $Ax=b$ has a unique solution for each $b$, not only for a given $b$, to say that $A$ is invertible.

Comment: that's not really true, having a unique solution for one fixed $b$ implies having unique solutions for all $b$'s - see other answers. therefore you don't need any stronger assumptions on $A$. stated in the language of linear operators - such an operator is injective if and only if $ker\, A = \{ 0 \}$

Answer (score 0):

Since $A$ is a $n$-by-$n$ matrix, the linear transformation $T: x \mapsto Ax$ is one-to-one $\implies$ linear transformation $T: x \mapsto Ax$ is invertible $\implies$ $A$ is invertible.

Suppose that $Ax=b$ and $Av = Au = 0, v\neq u$. Then $A(x+v) = A(x+u) = b$, whereby $x+v \neq x+u$.

$\therefore Ax=b $ for some unique $x \implies$ either there is no $v$ such that $Av=0$ or there is a unique $v$ such that $Av=0$.

Since $A0=0$, we conclude that there is a unique $v$ such that $Av=0$, and thus $T$ is one-to-one.

$\therefore A$ is invertible. (Line 1)