# If $A\vec x=b$ has a unique solution, then what do we know about $A\vec x=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> If $A\vec x=b$ has a unique solution, what do you know, if anything, about the equation $A\vec x=0$?

I'm having trouble seeing any relation at all.

Comment: Does it have a unique solution too?

Comment: If you do not see a relation at all, look around this site, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791750/how-do-we-know-that-if-ax-b-has-a-unique-solution-a-is-invertible), for a start.

Answer (score 0):

Let $b\neq 0$. Then suppose that there is a non-zero solution $z $, of $Ax=0$. Let $y\neq 0 $ be the unique solution of $Ax=b $. Then $z+y$ is another solution of $Ax=b$. 
This contradicts the uniqueness of the solution $y $. Hence it must be that $z=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x^*$ satisfies $Ax^*=0$ and let $x^{**}$ be the unique solution to $Ax=b$. Hence, $x^*+x^{**}$ is, also, a solution to $Ax=b$ and consequently $x^*+x^{**}=x^{**}$. Therefore, $x^*=0$ is the unique solution to $Ax=0$.