# On the uniqueness of linear regression in $\mathcal{L}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, hilbert-spaces, positive-definite, linear-regression

Let $x,y_1,\dots,y_k$ be random variables in $\mathcal{L}_{\mathbb{R}}^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. Let $[x],[y_1],\dots,[y_k]$ be their corresponding equivalent classes in $L_{\mathbb{R}}^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$.

$L^2$ is real Hilbert space and $\mathcal{G}:=\text{span}\{[y_1],\dots,[y_k] \}$ is a finite dimensional (hence closed) subspace of $L^2$. By the Hilbert space projection theorem there exist a vector $\hat{\beta}\in\mathbb{R}^k$ such that

$$E([x]-[y]'\hat{\beta})^2=\inf_{\beta\in\mathbb{R}^k} E([x]-[y]'\beta)^2$$

where $[y]:=([y_1],\dots,[y_k])'$.

**Question:** Is $\hat{\beta}$  also such that

$$E(x-y'\hat{\beta})^2=\inf_{\beta\in\mathbb{R}^k} E(x-y'\beta)^2$$

where $y:=(y_1,\dots,y_k)'$ and conversely? Also, is it true that $\hat{\beta}$ is unique if and only if $C:=E(yy')$ is positive definite?

Regarding the second question, if $E(yy')=E([y][y]')$ is positive definite, then by the orthogonality condition for projection we must have $\hat{\beta}=E([y][y]')^{-1}E([x][y])=E(yy')^{-1}E(xy)$. But what about the only if part?

EDIT: The orthogonality condition for $\hat{\beta}$ is

$$E([x][y])=E([y][y]')\hat{\beta}$$

By the projection theorem there is at least one vector $\hat{\beta}$ satisfying this condition, and conversely any $\hat{\beta}$ satisfying this condition determines a solution. Since $E([y][y]')=E(yy')$ is positive semi-definite by construction, $E([y][y]')$ is positive-definite if and only if it is invertible. If $E([y][y]')$ is not invertible, then from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/791750/522332) we see that the orthogonality condition does not have a unique solution. Since a system of linear equations has either zero, one, or infinitely many solutions, we conclude that there are  infinitely many solutions $\hat{\beta}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124213/discussion-on-question-by-alphie-on-the-uniqueness-of-linear-regression-in-mat).

Comment: You may use MathJax to render mathematics in the chat!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $X$,$Y_1,\ldots,Y_k$ are (real valued, the complex case is handle similarly) functions in $L_2(\mu)$ and Let $\mathcal{H}_k:=\operatorname{span}(Y_1,\ldots,Y_k)$.

The projection theorem guarantees that there exists a unique function $\widehat{X}\in\mathcal{H}_k$ such that
$$ \widehat{X}=\operatorname{arg}\min_{Z\in\mathcal{H}_k}\|X-Z\|_{L_2}$$
moreover, $X-\widehat{X}\in\mathcal{H}^\perp_k$, that is $\langle X-\widehat{X},Z\rangle:=0$ for all $Z\in\mathcal{H}_k$. (Here $\langle U,V\rangle :=\int UV\,d\mu$).

As $\widehat{X}\in\mathcal{H}_k$, there exists $\boldsymbol{\alpha}=[\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k]^\intercal\in\mathbb{R}^k$ such that
$\widehat{X}=\alpha_1Y_1+\ldots \alpha_kY:=\boldsymbol{\alpha}\cdot\boldsymbol{Y}$, where $\boldsymbol{Y}=[Y_1,\ldots,Y_k]^\intercal$. The problem that the OP is interested is that of necessary and sufficient conditions for uniqueness of $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$.

Since $X-\widehat{X}\in\mathcal{H}^\perp_k$,  $\boldsymbol{\alpha}\in\mathbb{R}^k$ satisfies $\widehat{X}=\boldsymbol{\alpha}\cdot\boldsymbol{Y}$ iff $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$satisfies the linear equations
$$\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
\langle X,Y_1\rangle\\
\ldots\\
 \langle X,Y_k\rangle\end{pmatrix} &= \begin{pmatrix} \langle Y_1,Y_1\rangle &\ldots &\langle Y_k,Y_1\rangle\\
\vdots &\ldots &\vdots\\
\langle Y_1,Y_k\rangle &\ldots &\langle Y_k,Y_k\rangle
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \alpha_1\\ \vdots\\ \alpha_k\end{pmatrix}\\
\langle X,\boldsymbol{Y}\rangle &= \langle \boldsymbol{Y}\boldsymbol{Y}^\intercal\rangle\,\boldsymbol{\alpha}
\end{align}
$$

If the $\{Y_1,\ldots,Y_k\}$ are linearly independent, then the matrix $A:=\langle \boldsymbol{Y}\boldsymbol{Y}^\intercal\rangle$ is invertible, in which case $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ is unique. One way to see this is by constructing first an orthonormal basis for $\mathcal{H}_k$ through the [Gram-Schmidt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) applied to the ordered basis $(Y_1,\ldots,Y_k)$. The expression for $\widehat{X}$ in terms of this new basis is easily obtained (and unique) by calculation of Fourier coefficients. Then, we invert the GS procedure  to recover the expression for $\widehat{X}$  in terms of the ordered basis $(Y_1,\ldots,Y_k)$.

In general (for example when $\{Y_1,\ldots,Y_k\}$ are not linearly independent) the matrix $A$ is not invertible. Still, we can use a generalize inverse (there are infinitely many of them) to obtain expression for a set of coefficients $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$. Amongst all solutions (and generalized inverses) there is one that is special and widely used. This is the [Moore-Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) $A^+$. the special solution $\boldsymbol{\alpha}_*=A^+\langle X,\boldsymbol{Y}\rangle$ will have the additional property that
$$
\boldsymbol{\alpha}_*=\operatorname{\arg}\inf\{|\boldsymbol{\alpha}|_2:\widehat{X}=\boldsymbol{\alpha}\cdot\boldsymbol{Y}\}
$$

**Observation:** If $\{Y_1,\ldots,Y_k\}$ are linearly independent and thus, when $A$ is invertible,   $A^+=A^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see what you mean. So in the end the answer to my original question: Is $\hat{\beta}$ is unique if and only if $E(yy')$ is positive-definite? is yes.

Comment: Ok and what about my first question: The problems with and without equivalence classes have the same solutions right? I mean that the problem is the same if we use $[x],[y_1],\dots,[y_k]$ or $x,y_1,\dots,y_k$. (Since integration results are invariant to null modifications)

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your time. Before I accept your answer may I ask if there is something in the EDIT part of my post that I should change, or are my statements correct?

Comment: As I understand the summary is : 1) $\hat{\beta}$ is a solution if and only if it satisfies the condition $E(xy)=E(yy')\hat{\beta}$. 2) There exists at least one such  $\hat{\beta}$ by the projection Theorem. 3) If $E(yy')$ is invertible $\hat{\beta}$ is unique. 4) If $E(yy')$ is not invertible there are infinitely many possible solutions $\hat{\beta}$, but there is still a unique solution of minimum norm $\hat{\beta}=E[yy']^+E[xy']$. Is that it?